# How can i throw exception to the value from app.config file

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, app-config

I was said to import sales tax rate from app.config file. In my app.config file i have two tax value GST and PST. How can i import this string value to my program code plus convert to decimal value and then add it . I have done till and i am receiving an error of throw exception. How can i throw exception ?? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
public decimal SalesTax 
        {
            get
            {
                decimal rateGST = Decimal.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rateGST"]);
                decimal ratePST = Decimal.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ratePST"]);
                return Subtotal * (rateGST + ratePST);
            }
        }
```

my App.config file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <!--Government Sales Tax-->
    <add key ="rateGST" value="5"/>

    <!--Provincial Sales Tax-->
    <add key="ratePST" value="8"/>

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What exception was thrown? Also consider using Decimal.TryParse in an if statement in the event there is an issue with the assignments. Also are you sure Subtotal in a valid state?

Comment: Hie Subtotal is my property which gives decimal value and i am getting error :Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
using System;
namespace demo
{
    class Class1
    {
        public decimal Subtotal { get; set; } //= 5;
        public decimal SalesTax
        {
            get
            {
                decimal rateGST = Decimal.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.rateGST);
                decimal ratePST = Decimal.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.ratePST);
                decimal result = Subtotal * (rateGST + ratePST);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```